# Execute Pepper webpage on computer

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

So I want to use the console of Mozilla in my computer to see what errors have the page that is normally executed by Pepper robot in his tablet, because  `console.log()` is not displayed on Choregraphe log.

I have tried to call the robot `qimessaging.js`  library from computer but it throws an error:

> SyntaxError: The URI is malformed. qimessaging.js:12

The html is there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://nao:nao@192.168.1.238/libs/qimessaging/1.0/qimessaging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/video.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width = "320px" height = "240px"></canvas>
    <p id="log">log</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to call the `qimessaging.js` without errors to test the web in my computer?

Comment: I don't think you can import an url with username/password in it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `console.log()` you can use `alert()`.

Also you can connect with your PC browser with this link `robot_ip/apps/your_app_name/index.html'`, but your `index.html` must be in sub folder named `html`.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the *lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior* from a URL?

Comment: Ok. finded -> `http://ip/apps/.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

You can also test from your computer if you import the script from the robot directly:

```
<script src="http://12.34.56.78/libs/qi/2/qi.js"></script>
```

Then when you open a session, add the robot url as a third argument of the `QiSession`:

```
QiSession( onSuccess, onError, "12.34.56.78:80" );
```

Then your browser will connect to your remote robot.